# troubles with customizable jquery alert box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to get it so a alert box shows up after a query to the database has been made and the user has been headered back to a page on my website with a js alert box telling them success or something went wrong.

I found a jquery script but I just cant seem to get it to work/run when required. Below are 2 snippets of code from 2 pages. 1 page is the index and the other is the php/MySQL process.

Below is the code on my index page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>........</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


/////////////////////////////BELOW IS THE CCS INCLUDE FOR THE ALERT
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-alerts.css">

/////////////////////////////BELOW IS THE JQUERY INCLUDE FOR THE ALERT
<script src="jquery/jquery-alerts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="pageMiddle">

//////////////////This is the $_SEESION ARRAY CONTAINING THE ALERT TRIGGER
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['error5301']) && $_SESSION['errors']['error5301'] == 1) { ?>
<script>
alert = function(message, title, callback){
$.alerts.alert(message, title, callback); };
</script>
<?php } ?>

THIS IS JUST CONTENT ON THE WEBSITE...................

</div>

//////////////THIS IS TO UNSET THE ERROR $_SEESION
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']))
{
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code on my PHP/MySQL process page after the process has taken place. this is directly after the query and within the same set of { } as the query. The header works fine.

```
header("location: index.php");
$_SESSION['errors']['error5301'] = 1;
session_write_close();
exit();
```

Below is the website I got the jquery from and the alert box I am trying to sort out is one at the top of the page

```
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/
```

Thank you for your time and I look forward to your help.

Comment: have you called that jquery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be I think you havent called the function..
just put

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['error5301']) && $_SESSION['errors']['error5301'] == 1) { ?>
<script>
 $.alerts.alert(message, title, callback);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have just tried that and I also tried that before I posted here and it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: try putting it in

`$(document).ready( function() {
 $.alerts.alert(message, title, callback);
});
`

Comment: so it looks like this? `<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['error5301']) && $_SESSION['errors']['error5301'] == 1) { ?>
<script>
 $(document).ready( function() {  $.alerts.alert(message, title, callback); });
</script>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: do you use `developer tools` in firefox? it will show you which error you are having in your javascript.. Please install it from `add-ons` in firefox... and tell me which error are you having..

Comment: I just got a email from the devs of the jquery. he said that if I am using a new version on jquery then I may need to changed some of the script so not looking good for me. Looks like I may need to look for a different alert window or something. I have also downloaded and install `developer tools` and the error i get is `TypeError: $.alerts is undefined`

Comment: yeah,, than this must be a jquery error.. check wether the include path is correct or not..

Comment: It is in the same file as another jquery I use for a calendar module. I have the same path as that except the name is called the file name what the required jquery is called. once again thank you for your help

Comment: this is a link to the jquery file from the actual site I got it from `http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js`

Comment: I have found the reason why. It is because of the fact the jquery I am running is to up to date for the function. Thank you for the help

Comment: I have put your answer as an excepted one because it is correct. it is my jquery what is the problem not your code but you already knew that :)

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer .. good to hear that your problem is solved now... @Luke